# Hardhat HTTPS RPC endpoint

Tags: hardhat, json-rpc

Is there a way to ser Hardhat RPC endpoint as HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my [Hardhate template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for you response, seeing your template I realized that maybe I was not clear: I would like to have HTTPS RPC for my local instance of Hardhat.

Comment: You could use nginx as some sort of proxy.